# Rename return "EPERM: operation not permitted" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my windows server, I found the fs.rename function always return the below error:

> error code is Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\javascript\nodejs\a.txt' -> 'C:\javascript\nodejs\b.txt'

The below are the test code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFileSync('a.txt',"This is a file")
fs.writeFileSync('b.txt',"This is another file")

fs.rename('a.txt','b.txt',function (err) {
            console.log("error code is " + err);
       });

var text = fs.readFileSync('b.txt', "utf-8");

console.log(text)
```

However, in the current folder, I do see the original file "a.txt" as well as the new renamed file "b.txt".

Comment: Doing an asynchronous rename while at the same time synchronously reading from the target location is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, you are right. I did not notice this. Actually I'm using the above code to test the permission of a server. BTW, can I vote your comments in Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

[`fs.rename`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) is just a wrapper to `rename`, and according to [`rename` docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html):

```
EPERM or EACCES
  The directory containing oldpath has the sticky bit (S_ISVTX)
  set and the process's effective user ID is neither the user ID
  of the file to be deleted nor that of the directory containing
  it, and the process is not privileged (Linux: does not have
  the CAP_FOWNER capability); or newpath is an existing file and
  the directory containing it has the sticky bit set and the
  process's effective user ID is neither the user ID of the file
  to be replaced nor that of the directory containing it, and
  the process is not privileged (Linux: does not have the
  CAP_FOWNER capability); or the filesystem containing pathname
  does not support renaming of the type requested.
```

You probably have no permissions to delete the file or the target file name already exists.

Comment: Downvoted because OP is clearly talking about Windows and this answer refers to linux,

Comment: @Dog it's referred in nodejs doc https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback

Answer (score 0):

After huge struggle found the solution for me ..

"Create new folders"
mkdir E:\Buildagent\npm
mkdir E:\Buildagent\npm-cache

"move npm prefix and the cache"
robocopy c:\Users\the-build-user\AppData\Roaming\npm E:\Buildagent\npm
robocopy c:\Users\the-build-user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache E:\Buildagent\npm-cache /E /MOVE

"Update the npm config for prefix and cache"
npm config set prefix E:\Buildagent\npm
npm config set cache E:\Buildagent\npm-cache

https://alastaircrabtree.com/fixing-intermittant-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-npm-install/